# why i'm seeing "Standard page view" & "Standard page edit" link on every visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, sales-cloud, sales

Since last week or two i'm noticing these two links on all of the visualforce pages. is this a new feature?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Incognito/secure mode?

Comment: Strange, I'm seeing this too. ONLY in a scratch org though.

Comment: This is only happening in chrome browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, this is due to another chrome extension.
I removed it and those links doesnt show up anymore.

Comment: For the next person: I think that this issue is caused by the [Salesforce Change Set Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-hel/gdjfanbphogooppaefebaaoohdcigpoi?hl=en-US) by Susan Bohme